# Troubble understanding the loop in selection sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Regarding Selection Sort Algorithm, I do not get whats the difference in the second loop of the second function. Let's say my array has 10 elements and we use zero-based index. So, in the `for` loop from the select function we go from index 1 (start+1) to index 9, since the range function does not include the last element.

```
def select(array, start):
    minIndex = start

    for j in range(start + 1, len(array)):
        if array[minIndex] > array[j]:
            minIndex = j

def selection_sort(array):
    
   # If I put len(array) removing the -1, I get it sort it anyway
    for i in range(len(array) - 1 ): # Here, I do not get it
        minIndex = select(array, i)
        tmp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[minIndex]
        array[minIndex] = tmp
```

If you look closer to the line `for i in range(len(array) - 1 ):`, when I remove the "-1" I get the array sorted anyway. Also, If I put `len(array) - 4` I still get the array sorted. Could you please give me a hand to solve my inquiry?

Comment: What would you swap the last element with?

Comment: With nothing, with none. Good call! But still, If I put only len(array) I get it sorted. Instead of putting len(array-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I remove the "-1" I get the array sorted anyway

That's to be expected, you're just wasting one comparison searching which index is smallest in a single element array (from `len()` to `len()`).

> Also, If I put len(array) - 4 I still get the array sorted.

Actually you don't.  Try with array `[2, 1]` for example.  Or even with array `[2, 1, 1, 1, 1]` or `[8, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]`.  You can only get away if switching `len() - 4` items is enough to reach a sorted state -- which might be the case with crafted tests, if the list is sorted in reverse, or already sorted near the end.

It boils down to how select sort works: you pick the lowest value in the unsorted range, and swap it with the one that was at the start of the range you're looking at, and make your way up the indices.  So first you put the lowest value from index `n` at index `0`, and whatever was at index `0` at index `n`.  Then do the same to index `1` on the remaining range `[1:]`.  If luck has it so you swap the elements directly to their final place, it'll "work" with less iterations, but you can only be sure until you chcked all of `[0:-1]` -- and no need to go all the way to `[0:len()]` as the last element will have been sorted by the previous step, as it ought to be higher or equal to `len()-1` to having been put after it.